# One of three php variables not being seen correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have this url:

```
http://nbastats.org/np2pp2.php?firstname=abc&lastname=def&firstseason=1900
```

These are my PHP variables:

```
$firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
$lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
$firstseason = $_GET['firstseason'];
```

Then my SQL:

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO playerRegSeason 
       (playerID, year, teamID, gp, minutes, pts, oreb, dreb, reb, 
        asts, stl, blk, turnover, pf, fga, fgm, fta, ftm, tpa, tpm)

       SELECT playerID, $year, '$team', $gp, $minutes, $pts, $oreb, 
         $dreb, $reb, $asts, $stl, $blk, $turnover, $pf, $fga, $fgm, 
         $fta, $ftm, $tpa, $tpm FROM players WHERE firstname='".$firstname."' 
       AND lastname='".$lastname."' AND firstseason='".$firstseason."'";
```

And finally the error message I receive:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' FROM players WHERE 
firstname='abc' AND lastname='def' AND firstseason=' at line 7
```

I know that $firstseason is being pulled because I am able to echo it, but for some reason it is not working within the SQL statement even though the other two are. I am assuming that it has something to do with that being a number when the others are strings. Only reason I say that is because it's the only thing I can see that is different. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

If I echo my SQL it reads like this: (so it is definitely getting the number, but I still have the error above.

```
INSERT INTO playerRegSeason (playerID, year, teamID, gp, minutes, pts, oreb, dreb, reb, 
asts, stl, blk, turnover, pf, fga, fgm, fta, ftm, tpa, tpm) SELECT playerID, 1900, '', 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, , FROM players WHERE firstname='abc' 
AND lastname='def' AND firstseason='1900'
```

and my code to execute:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql2)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Show the whole query after the PHP variables are interpolated. Also, show the PHP where you execute the query. You're running two queries at once and lack a semi-colon between them. Plus mysql_* functions do not support multi-query.

Comment: try SELECT * FROM players WHERE firstname='".$firstname."' AND lastname='".$lastname."' AND firstseason='".$firstseason."'";

do you get any results?

Comment: as an aside, please sanitise your input to prevent sql injections.

Comment: And read up on sql-injections, because what you are showing here looks crazy dangerous.

Comment: i think you're getting the error because you're putting a dollar sign in front of all the column names.  But yeah crazy dangerous seems an apt description.

Comment: @JoeT They are not columns, but php variables being plugged into a database.

Comment: well the last 2 have no values as evidenced by your echoed SQL, `..., 5, 5, , FROM...`  Looks like $tpa, $tpm are undefined...?

Comment: You are not define the last 2 variables.

Comment: I have removed the last two variables, and now it seems to work but it is only assigning the number '1' instead of the number '1900.'
Here is the new error:
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM players WHERE firstname='abc' AND lastname='def' AND firstseason='1' at line 7

Comment: @James What random letters are you referring to?

Comment: @James I don't have any of those letters you mentioned. The ones I do have are common abbreviations for basketball statistics.

Comment: It was just advice. I'm sure not all developers know basketball. Or could possibly know what variable types each term will be. (ie $blk is always an integer...)

Comment: echo your SQL again, the error generally occurs immediately before the part of your query shown with `the right syntax to use near`; iow your last var is probably still bogus.  If you wrap all your vars in quotes (like you did with $team), then it won't matter that it's bogus.  Well it might matter later, but it probably will allow the query to run.